# Insert strings into dictionary of file paths using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, insert, filenames

so I have a dictionary of file paths that looks like this:

```
import os

main_path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python files'

dict_path_old2 = {'A': os.path.join(main_path, 'Alpha') + f'\\filenames.csv',
                 'B': os.path.join(main_path, 'Beta') + f'\dont have.csv',
                 'C': os.path.join(main_path, 'Charlie') + f'\\an obvious.csv',
                 'D': os.path.join(main_path, 'Delta') + f'\pattern.csv',
                 }
```

I am not too familiar with advance techniques of manipulating strings and am looking for a pythonic way to insert the string `'copy'` before the name of the file for every value in the dictionary, so that the new dictionary looks like this:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python files\Alpha\copy filenames.csv
C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python files\Beta\copy dont have.csv
C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python files\Charlie\copy an obvious.csv
C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python files\Delta\copy pattern.csv
```

I know regular expressions can achieve this, but I don't know how and would like someone to show me how it is done. If there are ways more pythonic than regular expressions that can achieve the same goal, feel free to show me as well, because it is great to learn more ways to achieve the same goal.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that `os.path` accepts multiple positional arguments so you could use `os.path.join(main_path, 'Alpha', f'filenames.csv')` and so on.

Comment: Actually, not doing so and including the `\\ ` will break the portability, which I think is the whole point of using `os.path` in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os.path` you could do something like:

```py
dict_path = {
   k: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), 'copy ' + os.path.basename(path))
   for k, path in dict_path_old.items()
}
```

Comment: Note that using `os.path` we can build a portable solution nicely, which would be harder with regex

Comment: Really appreciate it. So in future whenever I get to deal with paths, I should always think of os.path before regex?

Comment: I'm not sure if you should go for regexp for performance critical code, but as a rule of thumb I would recommend to use `os.path` to deal with paths

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
for k, v in dict_path_old2.items():
    dict_path_old2[k] = re.sub(r'\\([^\\]+)$', '\copy \\1', dict_path_old2[k])
```

**Data:**

```
dict_path_old2 = {
    'A': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\all python files\\Alpha\\filenames.csv',
    'B': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\all python files\\ Beta\\filenames.csv',
    'C': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\all python files\\Charlie\\filenames.csv',
    'D': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\all python files\\Delta\\filenames.csv'
}
```

Comment: just ran the code; it raised an error.: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: tried replacing `iteritems()` with `items()`, it raised another error: `error: bad escape \c`

Comment: My code [is working in this Python demo](https://rextester.com/MGYK72767).  I can only guess that maybe you are not running exactly what I am running.

Comment: The reason could be that I am using Python 3.7.3, and the demo is 2.7.12